# Not able to send email using sendmail

Tags: python, email, smtp, sendmail

I am trying to send an email using following code,I don't see any error and the message `Success! Email Sent'` gets printed but I dont get any email?how to debug this?any pointers on why I am not getting the email?

```
from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.MIMEText import MIMEText
import smtplib,time
import traceback
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, call

TO = ['username@company.com', 'username@company.com' ]
CC = ['username@company.com']
SENDER = "username@company.com"
timestr = time.strftime("%m/%d/%Y at %H:%M:%S")
SUBJECT = str("Test email " + timestr)

msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
msg['Subject'] = SUBJECT
msg['From'] = SENDER
msg['To'] = ",".join(TO)
msg['Cc'] = ",".join(CC)
msg['Content-Type'] = "text/html; charset=utf-8"
msg['Content-Transfer-Encoding'] = "quoted-printable"
msg['MIME-Version']="1.0"

EMAIL = ""
CONTENT = """\
        <html>
            <head></head>
            <style type='text/css'>
            body {
            background-color: #F8F8F8 ;
            }
            h3 {
            color: blue;
            text-align: left;
                }
            p {
            font-family: 'Avenir Next' !important;
            font-size: 20px;
            }
            table {
                 border-collapse: collapse;
            }

            table, th, td {
                  border: 1px solid black;
            }

            th {
                background-color: #99CCFF;
                color: white;
            }
            </style>
            """

REST = """\
            <body>
                {0}
            </body>
        </html>""".format(EMAIL)

CONTENT += REST
#print(CONTENT)
emailHTML = MIMEText(CONTENT, 'html')
msg.attach(emailHTML)

smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP('mail.company.com')
smtpObj.ehlo()
smtpObj.starttls()
smtpObj.login('username@company.com', 'password815')

try:
    p = Popen(["/usr/sbin/sendmail", "-t", "-oi"], stdin=PIPE)
    p.communicate(msg.as_string())
    print('Success! Email Sent')
except:
    print traceback.format_exc()
    print("ERROR Sending Email : Email was not sent")

smtpObj.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You're going through all the pain of constructing an smtp object, opening a connection with it, and at the end - send the message through an external process? Why?
You're almost there, just try sending it in your python code.

In the try block, change the `Popen` code with this:

```
try:
    recipients = TO + CC
    smtpObj.sendmail(SENDER, recipients, msg.as_string())
except:
    print traceback.format_exc()
    print("ERROR Sending Email : Email was not sent")
finally:
    smtpObj.quit()  # the connection stays open even if an exception was raised, thus the quit() is here
```